# DynamicProxyFactory Usage

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dynamic-proxy

need some help with `DynamicProxyFactory`, i am creating a small app with WCF [C#], need to dynamically generate the proxy classes at run time.

I am not able to find any good page on how to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I had seen it earlier too, but just now managed to get it working!